# Collection-type Dependency Property - can't get rid of singleton

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, dependency-properties

Good evening!

I have a class inherited from the WPF extended toolkit's richTextBox to which I added a dependency property of a ObservableCollection type and the right wrapper for it.
I want to use this property to store the text of InlineUIContainers which I add to the FlowDocument and data-bind them to an ObservableCollection variable.

My problem is that all the instances of this richTextBox store their data in the same place (singleton).

I've tried using List, initializing the property in a constructor (like in the code sample below) - with SetValue as well. I've set the FrameworkMetadataProperty default value to null and still no luck (in this case it actually gives me "object not initialized" error when trying to add items).

I've run out of ideas. I've been googling it for the last two hours, but I still can't figure out why the instances aren't storing the values independently.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
public class RichTextBoxWithDataBoundableTokens : Xceed.Wpf.Toolkit.RichTextBox
{ 
    public static readonly DependencyProperty TokensContentsProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("TokensContents", typeof(ObservableCollection<object>), typeof(RichTextBox), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(new ObservableCollection<object>()));
    public ObservableCollection<object> TokensContents { get { return (ObservableCollection<object>)GetValue(TokensContentsProperty); } set { SetValue(TokensContentsProperty, (ObservableCollection<object>)value); } }

    public RichTextBoxWithDataBoundableTokens()
        : base()
    {
        TokensContents = new ObservableCollection<object>();
    }
}
```

This is how I use the Control:

```
    RichTextBoxWithDataBoundableTokens test = new RichTextBoxWithDataBoundableTokens()
    test.TokensContents.Add("some object");
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi set typeOf(RichTextBoxWithDataBoundableTokens ) instead of typeOf(RichTextBox) in Register method . I hope this will help.